# Ubuntu install fails on Acer Switch 312-31

Tags: system-installation, uefi, 19.04, acer

I have set the BIOS UEFI password in my [Acer Switch 312-31](https://www.acer.com/ac/de/DE/content/support-product/7246?b=1), then set UEFI safety check disabled. I booted the UBUNTU 19.04 AMD64 image and started installation.

The installer interupted with the message:
Das Paket grub-efi-amd64-signed konnte nicht in /target/ installert werden
(could not get installed).

It sent the info to Ubuntu. After that the installer crashed and started a live session using the settings from install.
Afterwords and also another time before I loaded grub64.efi using the BIOS.
I tried also the installer with the option partition something else and always failed at writing GRUB. Even with the option LVM it stopped with the same problem.
I do not use Windows, only Ubuntu; how can I run the installer without crashing at writing GRUB?

When I boot without USB-stick it boots into grub>

Can I load the kernel manually from there or using the live session to save grub to /target/?

Comment: Have you updated UEFI? Many Acer have needed that. Are you installing in UEFI boot mode without an ESP - efi system partition? Grub needs that for UEFI install. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2403167